Finder shortcuts all use Shift but Shift activates SLOW-motion opening animation (macOS monterey 12.7.6): How to defeat?
This is about Finder shortcuts, esp. Command-Shift-A (to open /Applications); not about the Dock, not about Mission Control.
When there is already a Finder window for /Applications, and it is minimized, the shortcut will open it instead of creating a 2nd window; but it defeats the intent of a "Shortcut" (to be "faster") if it does a 4-second animation.
Because the shortcut incorporates Shift, the Shift triggers slow-motion animation (arghh!). They are slow by design! I can't find a way to disable Finder animation; nor to edit those built-in shortcut keys.
In accessibility I have Reduce-Motion selected (from always). No help if I DISABLE Reduce-Motion either.
These settings don't help either (suspect 1st only applies to some newer OS-version):
% defaults read com.apple.finder FXEnableSlowAnimation
0
% defaults read com.apple.finder DisableAllAnimations
1
% defaults read -g NSAutomaticWindowAnimationsEnabled
0

My computer is a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015) running macOS Monterey 12.7.6.
Work-Around: Did find CAN change the keys!: prefs, Keyboard, Shortcuts, App-Shortcuts: Add Finder.app, add entries for menu=Applications etc.
But some I tried like Command-F1 STILL became Shift-Command-F1 in Finder. But Control-F1 or Option-Command-A works: did not auto add back Shift.
Is it possible to have my Finder shortcuts be fast without engaging the slow dock effect?

Did you defaults write those logical values to 0 or 1 and restart your mac after changing the logical values, or are the logical values shown above the default values? When you defaults write something you need to follow up with killing the relevant process, like UIServer, Dock, Finder or something along those lines... but a simple restart will do the trick too.

Welcome to Ask Different. You write "because the shortcut incorporates Shift, the Shift triggers slow-motion animation" and "it does a 10-second animation", but I can't reproduce it on my Mac after trying multiple times, even if Reduce Motion is selected in System Settings > Accessibility. What is the model / year of your Mac? Could it be that the Shift key is slightly jammed or sticky? Do you see this happening with both Shift keys?  Have you tested with a different keyboard?

Thank you. I did restart Dock & Finder, also logged-out and back in: no difference. Machine is MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015). Also tried left & right-side keys; and external wired USB and internal top-case keyboards (i.e.: all four sets of Shift & Command, two different A-keys (no I did not try combining A-key from keybd-1 with Shift or Command from keybd-2): no difference. Believe me, I have tried to release the Shift as fast as I can.

Thank you for trying an external keyboard. I wonder what is causing this behavor... How long have you been having this issue? Have you tried disabling Reduce Motion in Accessibility? (When replying, please mention my username in your comment like this @jaume so that I get a notification.)

@jaume Reduce-Motion either way no change. Updated question with Work-around details.

Thanks for checking, could it be that Sticky Keys or Slow Keys are enabled in System Settings > Accessibility > Keyboard?

@jaume Those AX settings are not set. Updated question with solution (in dock prefs).

I'm glad you solved the issue. It'd be great if could add an answer explaining how that specific command did the trick. You can then mark it as accepted and collect the reward while helping others with a similar issue. Thank you in advance.

SOLVED: This bool was enabled; disable it (& killall Dock) & problem solved. So Dock settings do impact the behavior of Finder shortcuts.
% defaults write com.apple.dock slow-motion-allowed -bool no

Comments on the question imply there should exist a different combo of settings that results in:
Shifted Finder shortcuts to re-open minimized folders does NOT animate; while if you right-click on the Finder in the Dock, and hold Shift while clicking on one of the Finder-windows, it WILL animate the opening (i.e. animate still happens on shifted mouse clicks). I don't have nor need that behavior, nor know how to achieve it.
